# how can I open the terminal and write commands in it with python code in ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have a lots of programs in different languages, but all of them do the same thing. If I give the same input to them, they all give the same output.

I want to process the output of each program, so I need output of each program in a string variable.

I want to write code in python to test these programs, in Ubuntu's terminal. I want to to work like the test code on the ACM servers.

How can I write/read in the Ubuntu terminal with python?

Comment: Usually, we write to the terminal in Python using the [`print` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

Comment: are you kidding?? i want to write commands in terminal like  cd ,cp, man .....

Comment: No, I wasn't kidding, I was trying to understand your question. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting an actual terminal *window* open that the user can see, and typing in it, would require some fiddly interaction with X11, which manages the desktop on Ubuntu.

But if all you want to do is to have your Python code run commands and look at their output, without necessarily having a real window, you probably want the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html). In current versions of Python 3, you can pass `capture_output=True` to `subprocess.Run()` along with your command, and then look at the output of the command (in `.stdout` under the returned `CompletedProcess`) to see if it looks like what you wanted it to look like.

Comment: actually  I want to process outputs but this method just print outputs I need output in string var

Comment: If you pass `capture_output=True`, the output should be captured into a variable. Try something like `var = subprocess.run(["ls", "-l", "/dev/null"], capture_output=True).stdout`.

Comment: and one another question is it good way to write Judge for challenges??

Comment: I wouldn't advise using this method to write a judging program unless you trust all challenge participants. You're directly running their code, which could do all sorts of things, including deleting the judge.